# Tensor product of reals and Gaussian numbers

Tags: tensor-products

I want to understand why there is an isomorphism:
$$\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[i] \simeq  \mathbb{C}.$$

Due to the universal property one can construct a linear map 
from $\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[i]$ to $\mathbb{C}$: $(r \otimes m+ni)\mapsto rm+rni$. 
How does one can create the inverse map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean $r\otimes(m+ni)\mapsto r(m+ni)$. The inverse map is $a+bi\mapsto a\otimes1 + b\otimes i$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @daOnlyBG The OP asked for the inverse map, I gave the inverse map. Do you understand the question? If you want me to elaborate on proving it's an inverse map, and any intuition regarding the situation, then that boilerplate comment is out of place.

Comment: I thought I understood it. The author explicitly asked for "How does one create.." not "what is the inverse map," and seeing that your response was in the "low quality post" queue, I noticed that detail. Apparently the author is quite alright with your post- and hey, that's fine, I have nothing against you or your post's accuracy- but I would have thought that the proper response would have included more of a "solution" instead of an outright "answer." Yes, the boilerplate comment is out of place, I agree. That's the automated response, unfortunately.